# Move only some images from a folder in python

Tags: python, file, shutil

I have 10500 images in one folder I would like to move only 8400 images to another folder. I am using shutil library to do that but my code moves all the files. I only want 8400.

```
path = "I:\\Hr_less_images\\"
output = "I:\\Hr_data\\Train\\"
files = os.listdir(path)
for index, file in enumerate(files):
    if index < 8401:
        src = path + file
        dst = output + file
        shutil.move(src,dst)
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. What problem are you facing? You can improve it a bit by breaking when you reach 8401.

Comment: All the images are moving from one folder to another I just want 8400 files to move not 10500

Comment: yes, that's what you code does. But to test it would be easy if you try to move 2 images. Then when it works change the number to 8400.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Could it be that you ran the file twice which resulted in *all* files eventually moved? Your code seems to do what it should...

Comment: An easier way to do this would be to slice the files list: `files[:8400]`

Comment: @PeterWood Easier but heavier (probably insignificant...).  Another way would be `for file in itertools.islice(files, 8400):`

Comment: Yes the code seems to be working , I think I ran it twice before